# How to set my date into yesterday?

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar

I am trying to create `UIDatePicker` in my project which maximum date should be that of yesterday instead of current date. Is there a way to set selected date as yesterday instead of selecting current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date

        let yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])!

        datePicker.maximumDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: yesterday, options: [])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```